# Email address columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What's the correct way to add a check constraint for columns that should only contain email addresses?

We've had buggy software in the past that's added garbage to email columns and I would like to prevent that from happening again.

---

Please note that "perfect" solutions are not expected. While full RFC compliance would be great, I think most of us can agree just catching obvious mistakes such as "domain/username" and "2017-12-3" would be enough.

And of course it cannot reject any valid email address.

Comment: I wouldnt add a check constraint at all. I would have our application verify the email address at creation time. If the user doesnt respond to the verification email it is a bad email address or the user doesnt care. Once its be validated you can just mark an IsValidated field or something

Comment: http://emailregex.com/ gives a few examples but nothing is bulletproof anymore.  email verification and a trigger that sets isValidated back to false when an update occurs is likely the surest approach.

Comment: @JonathanAllen - Did you check my answer?

Comment: If you can use CLR a simple way is to use the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class. If it throws an error when creating a new instance (assuming you call the constructor with only the email address) then you can assume the email address format is invalid.

Comment: The [problem with email validation](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) is that an email address could be almost anything now that domains can have almost any ending and that there are RFCs for [international email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email). I personally only check that the email address has a `@` and at least one `.` (and the dot check should be omitted in applications that allows intranet email addresses).

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez that would actually be enough for my use case. Mostly I'm looking to catch the obvious mistakes such as `domain/username` and `2017-12-3`.

Comment: I should test the CLR route and post it as an alternative answer for those who can take that dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
alter table your_table add constraint chk_email 
CHECK
(
     email like '%_@__%.__%' 
AND (CHARINDEX('.@', email) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('..', email) = 0)  -- prevent patterns like '.@' and '..'
AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(email))) - LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM([email])),'@','')) = 1 -- Single '@' is allowed
)
```

Comment: @SeanLange - Example?

Comment: Well, we can make it more perfect, please check the updated answer. Still we can add more conditions in it to prevent more invalid formats :)

Comment: Still entirely too brittle to be useful. There is little to no chance you can leverage straight t-sql for this kind of thing. Consider this one. ' @   .  ' Or here is another one. '@@@@@.@@'  These are extreme sure but you get the idea.

Comment: I know there are more, and i already told that we can add more conditions in it. What i provided is just an idea to implement this in this way, i don't know how to use regex here, in fact not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: You can't use full regex in t-sql.

Comment: It doesn't have to be perfect, it just needs to reject the most obvious errors while accepting all valid emails.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a before trigger which checks(use regular expression) if it is a valid email and if it is, then allow it to be added to the column.

Comment: The problem here is defining what is a valid email address. It is incredibly complex to say the least. Most table definitions do not allow for anywhere near enough data to allow for all possible valid email addresses.

Comment: Regular expression is the way to go.

Comment: I agree to a point but... What is your regular expression for a valid email? Then compare it to the RFC 2822 specs. It is staggering what is actually allowed in an email address and nearly any validator I have ever seen will not be 100% accurate.

Comment: And unless you use CLR you can't use a regular expression in sql server. :D

Comment: Email validation, it is similar to security which are basically layers of intermediate processes. It is up to you. Try starting of with some simple email regEx. and then try adding over it.

Comment: So in other words you don't actually have any substance for your answer. All you have to offer is to suggest they use a regular expression. I hate to say it but this isn't an answer.

Comment: You did not get me right. I can provide you with a regular expression for a valid email; it is maybe not what you really want.

Comment: Unless you post some details this isn't an answer.

Comment: The answer provided by Md.Suman Kabir uses a very simple and generic regex.

Comment: Yes it does...but it is not really a regex and way too many invalid values would pass.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to have one of your classes to process that would be email address before storing it.

Comment: I see no reason to use a trigger when a check constraint could do the same thing.

Comment: Check constraint is very limited in term of control whereas with a trigger you have a better control over the string you want to verify.

Comment: Check constraints can call user-defined functions. And those can do pretty much anything.